# Topologically characterizing metrizable spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, online-resources

There are some well-known theorems that imply that some metrizable spaces, when satisfying other topological properties, are unique up to homeomorphism. Here are a few examples, where "perfect" means "has no isolated points":

1. Every totally disconnected, perfect, compact metrizable space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set $\mathfrak{C}$ equipped with the Euclidean topology.
2. Every totally disconnected, perfect, countable metrizable space is homeomorphic to the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ equipped with the Euclidean topology.

What other results are there which uniquely identify metrizable topological spaces up to a homeomorphism?

Comment: As an honorable mention, in point-free topology, the only atomless complete Boolean algebra (which is a frame) with a countable dense subset (this is point-free second countability) is the regular open algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The irrationals are up to homeomorphism the only nowhere compact zero-dimensional Polish space.

Comment: Given the pre-eminence of the resl line in mathematics, it is worth mentioning the old result that it is characterised as a   conneced, locally connected, separable metric space in which every point is a cut point. (i.e., its complement has two components). This can be used to give such a characterisation of the closed unit interval.

Comment: There are many many such characterization theorems, see books in Infinite-Dimensional Topology and also papers of van Engelen, recent papers of Dijsktra and van Mill (on characterization of the complete Erdos space), characterization theorems of Torunczyk, etc. etc.

Comment: There are many such results in continuum theory, especially for spaces that are universal in some classes. $[0,1]$ is the only hereditarily equivalent locally connected plane continuum, while the pseudoarc is the only one which is not locally connected. The Lelek fan is the unique smooth fan with a dense set of endpoints. For each $P\subseteq \omega+1$ the Wazewski dendrite $W_P$ is the unique dendrite in which for every $p\in P$ the set of branching points of order $p$ is arcwise dense. If a continuum $X$ is homogeneous and every subcontinuum is an arc, then $X$ is a solenoid etc. etc.

Comment: Perfect countable metrizable spaces are homeomorphic to the rationals, even without the hypothesis of totally disconnected.